# JPA: primary key violation when saving an entity with many to one

Tags: java, jpa

I have 2 JPA Entities

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Config {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String data;

    @ManyToOne(cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    private Tenant tenant;
}


@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
class Tenant {  
    @Id
    private String tenantID;
}
```

and a repository

```
interface SolmanConfigPrivateRepository extends CrudRepository <Config, Long> {

}
```

I create new entities with the following code

```
public void addConfig(Config config){
    String tenantId = userProvider.get();
    config.setTenant(getCurrentTenant());
    Tenant tenant = new Tenant(tenantId);
    dbRepository.save(config);

}
```

I manage to save a Config using the save method of the repository.

If I try to save a new Config with the same tenant, I get an error

```
 Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY_KEY_9 ON PUBLIC.TENANT(TENANTID)
```

How can I tell JPA to not try to create a new Tenant if there is already another one in the database (but to reference the existing one instead)?

Comment: show the method in which you construct the entities and invoke the save

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're violating hibernate session. What you have to do, is to `find` `Tenant` from db by id, set entity picked up from the db (that certain reference) and then save. Otherwise, Hibernate will try to save instead of update.

```
public void addConfig(SolManConfig solManConfig){
    String tenantId = userProvider.get();
    solManConfig.setTenant(getCurrentTenant());
    Tenant tenant = tentantRepository.findOne(tenantId);
    dbRepository.save(solManConfig);
}
```

`Spring data JPA` has one method for save and update. It's save. When you pass a new object, it saves, otherwise it updates. What does it mean 'new object'? It means, an object which hasn't been extracted from the db.

Comment: Tenant tenant = tentantRepository.findOne(tenantId); does nothing to solManConfig. Did you mean:
Tenant tenant = tentantRepository.findOne(tenantId);
solManConfig.setTenant(tenant );
dbRepository.save(solManConfig); ?

Comment: @hipokito it does. You need to set cascades and eventually refresh the entity

Answer (score 0):

**How is the tenant id set?** It's obviously not generated (according to the JPA annotations), so I suppose you set it manually?

If you don't set it at all, the tenantID will be *null*, thus when inserting another tenant (which then also has tenantID *null*), the unique constraint will be violated.

Comment: I set it manually through the constructor (I've just edited my question)